# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with specifying first column as auto-increment value

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, import, load

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'index.csv'
INSERT INTO TABLE `aws_pricing`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 6 LINES;
```

Thing is, my table has the first column as `id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ... PRIMARY KEY (id)`, so I get :

> ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1

So index.csv has one column less. How do I get LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to work by specifying to auto-increment before reading each line from index.csv file ?

MySQL Ver 8.0.32

Comment: Use input preprocessing. Load the value for AI column into UDV and ignore its value.

Comment: You should always tag which database system and version you're using. I've updated the tags with the system, please add the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should name the columns you are importing

For example, this is from the [MySQL Documentation on LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

```
CREATE TABLE jokes
  (a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  joke TEXT NOT NULL);
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/jokes.txt' INTO TABLE jokes
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n%%\n' (joke);
```

So, in your case, name your columns after all the line and field escaping

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'index.csv'
INSERT INTO TABLE `aws_pricing`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (col1,col2,...)
IGNORE 6 LINES;
```

Just name all the columns except `id`